# Google Sheets - Count unique / distinct values within QUERY function (or any other function, but not using pivot table)

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, formulas

Is there a way to get the result from the Example sheet Columns J:K using a single function?

= is there a way to count unique / disctinct values within QUERY function, or any other single function that would create a pivot-like set of data with two columns?

In the example sheet I have a set of data, which I need to group by one column and count unique values in the other one. There's a workaround there, but it involves two formulas plus another one that would sort it properly (data set is growing and rows get added, so sorting manually is not the best option).

**Query** function (or, my knowledge of Query function) doesn't seem to be able to count unique values, so it's not working. Googling hasn't helped me much with this.

Since the data will grow, the idea is to **avoid pivots** here, and I'd need to update pivot filters all the time to list all new locations and have blanks excluded. Want to have it as automated as possible

**UPD:**

I found it! Thanks to [ahab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WW19vK_G1u1qmP5TzwqfSD8p4P92MVVr5vphcebVps/edit?usp=sharing), works like a charm.

If two columns follow each other:

```
 =ArrayFormula( SORT (QUERY( UNIQUE( TRIM(A:B) ); 
    "Select Col1, count(Col2) Where Col1<>'' Group by Col1 Order by Col1  
    Label Col1 '', count(Col2) '' " ; 0), 2, FALSE)
```

If there're not needed columns between the two columns that you need:

```
=ArrayFormula( sort(QUERY( UNIQUE( QUERY( TRIM(C4:H) , 
 "Select Col6, Col1 ") ) , "Select Col1, count(Col2) Where Col1<>'' 
  Group by Col1 Order by Col1  Label Col1 '', count(Col2) '' " , 0), 2, FALSE))
```

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14WW19vK_G1u1qmP5TzwqfSD8p4P92MVVr5vphcebVps/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! Thanks to [ahab](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/CoPSX5F6DEc), works like a charm.

If two columns follow each other:

```
 =ArrayFormula( SORT (QUERY( UNIQUE( TRIM(A:B) ); 
    "Select Col1, count(Col2) Where Col1<>'' Group by Col1 Order by Col1  
    Label Col1 '', count(Col2) '' " ; 0), 2, FALSE)
```

If there're not needed columns between the two columns that you need:

```
=ArrayFormula( sort(QUERY( UNIQUE( QUERY( TRIM(C4:H) , 
 "Select Col6, Col1 ") ) , "Select Col1, count(Col2) Where Col1<>'' 
  Group by Col1 Order by Col1  Label Col1 '', count(Col2) '' " , 0), 2, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table of data!A3:B22 with Rows as A and Values as B. Summerize Values by countunique and sort Rows by countunique decending.

Script version

```
function uniqueCountSort() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()//.getSheetByName("data")
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var val=s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 2).getValues()
  var l=val.length-1
  var val=val.sort()

  var newVal=[]
  for(var i=l;i>0;i=i-1){
    if(val[i][0]!=val[i-1][0]){
     newVal.push([val[i][0],val[i][1]])}
  else{
    if(val[i][1]!=val[i-1][1] && val[i][1]!=null){
      newVal.push([val[i][0],val[i][1]])
  }}
  }
var nvl= newVal.length-1
var countArray =[]
  for(var i=nvl; i>0; i=i-1) {
    var count = 0;
    if(newVal[i][0] != newVal[i-1][0]  && newVal[i-1][0]!=null){
       count=1;
       countArray.push([newVal[i][0],count])}
     else{
       count=0
      for(var j=nvl; j>0; j=j-1) {
          if(newVal[i][0] == newVal[j-1][0]  && newVal[i][0]!=null){
          count++}
      }
       countArray.push([newVal[i][0],count])
}
i=(i-count)+1
}
 countArray.sort(mySorting)
 var ret= ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, countArray.length,   2).setValues(countArray)
```

}

```
function mySorting(a,b) {
a = a[1];
b = b[1];
 return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? 1 : -1) 
}
```

I should tell you that I had trouble with your sample spreadsheet. It could not find the correct last row of data. I had to delete rows and columns and then add them again to get this to work. I could not find what was causing the problem. I an enclosing a link below of a copy of your spreadsheet that I tested this on.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RYfolLQGfsnY2-_-P67AYpB3KKHhT8WtR1vKUCKMtvk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: hi Ed, Thanks for your answer, but the idea is to avoid pivots here. Sorry, I didn't mention it initially. The data will grow and I'd need to update pivot filters all the time to list all new locations and exclude blanks. Want to have it as automated as possible, that was the reason to ask for help with a formula. (I'll add this to the request not to mislead others)

Comment: @VictorZhurbin Are you open to an apps script solution? I will post one if you are.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you! that works great. I'll leave this unanswered just because I'm still wondering if there's a way to do it using a formula